# Send serial message to device until it is online

Tags: linux, python-3.x, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to update the firmware of a controller through a serial interface. To do this, I must send a reboot message to the controller (no problem there) and then send another message (the character 'w') THE MOMENT it starts up so that it may start up in write mode. This is easily done with the minicom utility by pressing w continuously while the device restarts.

I want to achieve this functionality using python code instead, but I can't figure out how to send a message until the device is up without throwing exceptions (since the device is not connected).

This is what I have tried, but it does not work (with pyserial):

```
def send_w(serial_port, baud_rate):
    msgw = "w_"
    ans = ""
    ser = serial.Serial(port=serial_port, baudrate=baud_rate,timeout = 10)
    ser.write(msgw)
    ans = ser.read(24)
    ser.close()
    print(ans)
    return ans

def set_firmware_version(serial_port, baud_rate):
    s = ""
    try:
        with serial.Serial(serial_port,baud_rate,timeout=1) as ser:
            msgr = "%reset "+sk+"_"
            ser.write(msgr)
            ser.close()
            print("reset")
    except (IOError) as e:
        print("Error in: set_firmware_version")
        print(e)
        return s
    time.sleep(1)
    send_w(serial_port, baud_rate)

set_firmware_version(sp,br)
```

This gives the following error:

```
serial.serialutil.SerialException: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)
```

I also tried sending the messages in a loop with a short timeout, but had the same problem. Is there any way to send a message continuously and disregard exceptions if the device is not found?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mc_config.py", line 69, in <module>
    set_firmware_version(sp,br)
  File "mc_config.py", line 64, in set_firmware_version
    send_w(serial_port, baud_rate)
  File "mc_config.py", line 46, in send_w
    ans = ser.read(24)
  File "/home/avidbots/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 501, in read
    'device reports readiness to read but returned no data '
serial.serialutil.SerialException: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)
```

(I am using ubuntu 16.04 and python 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you put the excepting code into a `try` and then catch the exception with an `except serial.serialutil.SerialException {...}` block?

Clearly there's a significant window of time to submit the `w` ( otherwise the "press w" method wouldn't often work.)  Your requirement, then, would be to retry only the part of the code that's absolutely necessary to send the `w`, so that you send it quickly enough to "catch" the system in its bootup state.  Since the backtrace shows that the exceptions occurs in `send_w`, then you can add `try`/`except` blocks and a `while` loop around what is now one line at the end of `set_firmware_version`.

Instead of just this:

```
send_w(serial_port, baud_rate)
```

Something like this might solve the problem:

```
while True:
  try:
    send_w(serial_port, baud_rate)
    break
  except serial.serialutil.SerialException:
    pass # retry
```

You may need to change your imports to expose that exception, fyi.  And you may need to consider whether you're catching too many possible exceptions - it's possible that exception might also represent other errors that shouldn't be retried.  You might also need to add a small sleep time there - this is essentially a busy wait loop (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting).

Comment: Thank you, something very similar worked. I removed the sleep before calling the function, shortened the timeout on send_w  to 0.1 and set an ending condition on the loop instead of the break statement. pass for the exception was the key!